# Inter-rater agreement (raters >2) of non-random items

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data, fixed-effects-model, agreement-statistics

I ran a survey where participants (P) had to choose one category out of six (C1-C6) for each of five items.

The data looks like this:

```
      | P1 | P2 | P3 |...
-----------------------------------------------
Item1 | C1 | C1 | C2 |...
Item2 | C2 | C3 | C5 |...
Item3 | C1 | C2 | C1 |...
Item4 | C1 | C1 | C2 |...
Item5 | C1 | C4 | C4 |...
```

Sampling: The items were sampled not randomly - from a pool of items containing duplicates, I chose 5 unique ones that were representative and non-noisy. The participants were sampled randomly, and divided into three groups according to some preliminary questions.

Goal: I want to measure to what extent participants agreed in their category choice, and compare this agreement between groups. For example: did members of Group 1 agree on the category of item 1? And did members of Group 3 agree more than members of Group 1 and Group 2? Ideally, I would also compare whether the difference is statistically significant.

Which statistical test could I use?

Methods I considered [and why I can't use them]:

- Cohen's Kappa [Discarded because I have more than 2 raters.]
- Fleiss' Kappa [But the assumption that "subjects", here items, are random is not met.]
- ICC [But my items are fixed, not random]